# Attempt to read property "new_password" on array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem executing a method that changes the password of the user logged into the system, because it is not recognizing array column to change password. The error is `Attempt to read property "new_password" on array`.

- `dd($validations)`

```
    array:3 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/ChangePasswordController.php:22
      "current_password" => "12345."
      "new_password" => "67890."
      "confirm_new_password" => "67890."
    ]
```

- `method`

```
    public function updatePassword(ChangePasswordRequest $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user()->name;
        $validations = $request->validated();
        User::find(Auth::user()->id)->update(['password'=> Hash::make($validations->new_password)]);
        return redirect('change_password')->with('success-update-password',"$user changed your password with sucess.");
    }
```

Comment: Line that doesn't work ```User::find(Auth::user()->id)->update(['password'=> Hash::make($validations->new_password)]);```

Comment: `$validations['new_password']` should work. `->new_password` is for Objects, while `['new_password']` is for Arrays.

Comment: @TimLewis ```Add [password] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User].```

Comment: So in your `User.php` model, make sure you have `protected $fillable = ['password']`... Like the error says.

Comment: Also, `User::find(Auth::user()->id)` is redundant; just do `Auth::user()->update(...)`

Comment: ```password``` is found inside the ```fillable```.

Answer (score 0):

```
User::whereId(Auth::user()->id)->update(['password'=> Hash::make($validations['new_password'])]);
```